# Laravel Eloquent Group Result in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table called "grids".
Columns are id, floor, and grid.

```
id                 floor           grid
==========         =======       =======
1                     EG            LEFT
2                     EG            RIGHT
3                     DG            LEFT
4                     DG            RIGHT
```

When I get all my data with:

```
$data = Grid::all()
```

I have an array with 0 => Grid Object 1, 1 => Grid Object 2, and so on..

But how is it possible to group my Result in an array like this:

```
$data = array(
        'EG' => array(
            'LEFT' => Grid Object 1,
            'RIGHT' => Grid Object 2,
        )
        'DG' => array(
            'LEFT' => Grid Object 3,
            'RIGHT' => Grid Object 4,
        )
    )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to do that manually. Meaning loop through the collection and build the new structure

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $d){
    if(!isset($result[$d->floor])){
        $result[$d->floor] = array();
    }
    $result[$d->floor][$d->grid] = $d;
}
```

Comment: okay thanks. I feared it. I thought there might be a laravel eloquent function for this ...

Comment: Not as far as I know. But it's not "bad" when you have to do some things yourself.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As of present Laravel versions, you can use the groupBy function

```
$data = $data->groupBy('floor');
```

Will give you the desired array